# constants in an Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, static, constants

I'm creating a game with Cocos2D for iPhone. The following expression appears in a few places around the code:

```
CGFloat screenCenter = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width / 2.0;
```

I'd like to put this in a constants file or similar such that the expression isn't repeated all over the place. One idea is to put

```
#define SCREEN_CENTER [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width / 2.0
```

in `Constants.h` and just import as necessary. However I'm under the impression that it's better style/practice in Objective-C to use `static const` in some capacity.

How can I declare `screenCenter` in just one place using `static const` then re-use it throughout the code as necessary?

One potential benefit of this is doing the division only once instead of every time screen center is calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a compile-time expression, therefore you cannot make it a `static const`.

If you want to keep the `#define`, you need to wrap parens around it or you may introduce subtle bugs.

You may also want to consider using an inline function

```
inline CGFloat screenCenter() {
    return [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width / 2.0f;
}
```

Or you could hang it off of `CCDirector` directly. Assuming you don't own that class, you can use a category

```
@interface CCDirector (FunkyStuff)
- (CGFloat)screenCenter;
@end

@implementation CCDirector (FunkyStuff)
- (CGFloat)screenCenter {
    return self.winSize.width / 2.0f;
}
@end

...
x = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] screenCenter];
```

For added convenience you could even make it into a class method.

Comment: @SundayMonday: Well, you wanted it in a `const`, so I assume you were trying to minimize execution time. An `inline` function allows the compiler to skip the overhead of a function call and just inline the definition right into the callsite. Note that this requires the function implementation to be in the header file. Or you could just skip the `inline` part, since a function call overhead is probably not going to be a problem.

Comment: +1 I see. What do you think about just a static global variable that's initialized just once (as soon as the screen width is available)?

Comment: @SundayMonday: That's certainly an option, though you have to be careful to not modify it from anywhere that's not allowed to. This also assumes that the screen size cannot possibly change (which I would guess is a safe assumption, but I don't know Cocos2D so I don't know this for a fact).